# New Mac continues crashing even after changing memory

Tags: crash, kernel-panic

I am posting related to crashes I have had with my new Mac. The last time I posted about this someone had suggested to replace the memory cards since the previous crashes and report messages seem related to that. They thought it was either the memory or maybe a hardware issue. Replacing the memory seemed to work for awhile but now it's crashing again with new error messages. Below is the current crash message. I am guessing I will just need to bring the computer in to a store but wondering if anyone has any insight based on the report? Thank you in advance for any help/tips.

```
panic(cpu 16 caller 0xffffff80141b6113): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80141982d3, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff8d0c323c88, CR3: 0x000000047d0f7039, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000040, RCX: 0x0000000000000000, RDX: 0x0000000000000001
RSP: 0xffffffd902d43a60, RBP: 0xffffffd902d43aa0, RSI: 0x0000000000000360, RDI: 0xfffffebdc0000000
R8:  0x000ffffffffff000, R9:  0xfffffeb1d74c7360, R10: 0xffff8007a73fffff, R11: 0xffffff8014ef0080
R12: 0xffffff8d0c323c70, R13: 0x000000012b8b9000, R14: 0x0000000000fd755e, R15: 0x0000000000000000
RFL: 0x0000000000010283, RIP: 0xffffff80141982d3, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff8d0c323c88, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x10, PL: 1, VF: 5

Panicked task 0xffffff8737306bf8: 15 threads: pid 20930: PerfPowerService
Backtrace (CPU 16), panicked thread: 0xffffff9a6204f0c8, Frame : Return Address
0xffffffd902d43440 : 0xffffff801407207d 
0xffffffd902d43490 : 0xffffff80141c6164 
0xffffffd902d434d0 : 0xffffff80141b5c77 
0xffffffd902d43520 : 0xffffff8014012951 
0xffffffd902d43540 : 0xffffff801407235d 
0xffffffd902d43630 : 0xffffff8014071a07 
0xffffffd902d43690 : 0xffffff80147db40b 
0xffffffd902d43780 : 0xffffff80141b6113 
0xffffffd902d43900 : 0xffffff80141b5dfd 
0xffffffd902d43950 : 0xffffff8014012951 
0xffffffd902d43970 : 0xffffff80141982d3 
0xffffffd902d43aa0 : 0xffffff8014132308 
0xffffffd902d43b40 : 0xffffff8014131b98 
0xffffffd902d43c80 : 0xffffff80140f09a7 
0xffffffd902d43cc0 : 0xffffff801404c51a 
0xffffffd902d43d60 : 0xffffff80140632a2 
0xffffffd902d43dd0 : 0xffffff8014063927 
0xffffffd902d43ef0 : 0xffffff801419b533 
0xffffffd902d43fa0 : 0xffffff8014012db6 

Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff9a6204f0c8): PerfPowerServices

Mac OS version:
22G90

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Wed Jul  5 22:21:56 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.141.3~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 8295C77B-2AAB-3471-81B5-438F59B1A36D
roots installed: 0
KernelCache slide: 0x0000000013c00000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff8013e00000
Kernel slide:      0x0000000013cdc000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff8013edc000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8013d00000
System model name: iMac20,1 (Mac-CFF7D910A743CAAF)
System shutdown begun: NO
Hibernation exit count: 0

System uptime in nanoseconds: 181609440952519
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
  Uptime  : 0x0000a52c3e37495e
  Sleep   : 0x0000a4afd204bdea 0x00000000a15dda66 0x0000a4a415070723
  Wake    : 0x0000a4afdb2463c2 0x00000000a165b5b4 0x0000a4afd7713513
Compressor Info: 0% of compressed pages limit (OK) and 0% of segments limit (OK) with 0 swapfiles and OK swap space
Zone info:
  Zone map: 0xffffff80c71b8000 - 0xffffffa0c71b8000
  . PGZ   : 0xffffff80c71b8000 - 0xffffff80cf1b9000
  . VM    : 0xffffff80cf1b9000 - 0xffffff859ab52000
  . RO    : 0xffffff859ab52000 - 0xffffff8733e85000
  . GEN0  : 0xffffff8733e85000 - 0xffffff8bff81e000
  . GEN1  : 0xffffff8bff81e000 - 0xffffff90cb1b7000
  . GEN2  : 0xffffff90cb1b7000 - 0xffffff9596b50000
  . GEN3  : 0xffffff9596b50000 - 0xffffff9a624ea000
  . DATA  : 0xffffff9a624ea000 - 0xffffffa0c71b8000
  Metadata: 0xffffffa8b5148000 - 0xffffffa8d5148000
  Bitmaps : 0xffffffa8d5148000 - 0xffffffa8e1148000
  Extra   : 0 - 0

Probabilistic GZAlloc Report:
  Zone    : <unknown>
  Address : 0xffffff8d0c323c88
  Submap  : GEN1 [0xffffff8bff81e000; 0xffffff90cb1b7000)
  Kind    : wild deref, missing or invalid metadata
  Metadata: zid:0 inl:0 cl:0x0 0x0000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000

last started kext at 180974417208764: >!UAudio  560.2 (addr 0xffffff7fa9a8f000, size 335872)
last stopped kext at 180443466885355: >!UAudio  560.2 (addr 0xffffff7fa9a8f000, size 335872)
loaded kexts:
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    6440.7
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   131
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.9
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    4.1.4
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   4.1.4
>!ABridgeAudio!C    340.1
>!AGFXHDA   240.1
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 7.1.18
>!A!IKBLGraphics    20.0.6
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   7.1.18
>pmtelemetry    1
@filesystems.nfs    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
>usb.!UUserHCI  1
>!AHV   1
>!ADiskImages2  198.100.13
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 20.0.6
>!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
>!AMCCSControl  1.16
>BridgeAudioCommunication   340.1
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!UCardReader   554
|SCSITaskUserClient 482.120.2
>!UMass!SInterfaceNub   554
>BCMWLANFirmware4388.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4387.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4378.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   627.100.6
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   2142.140.9
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  11.0.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIeMac   1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AUserConsent  1
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    404
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.Compression    1
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
>!UAudio    560.2
>!AHIDKeyboard  231
>!AMultitouchDriver 6440.7
>!AInputDeviceSupport   6460.1
>!AHS!BDriver   6440.7
>IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6200HWLibs  1.0
>!AAudioClockLibs   240.1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  4.1.4
|IOAudio!F  440.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>IOHIDPowerSource   1
>!ACallbackPowerSource  1
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
>IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
|IOAVB!F    1140.6
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
>!ARSMChannel   1
|IORSM!F    1
>!AIPAppender   1.0
>!AGraphicsControl  7.1.18
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 4.1.4
@kext.AMDSupport    4.1.4
|IONDRVSupport  597
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1150.2
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOAccelerator!F2   475.40.6
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.1
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>driverkit.serial   6.0.0
@!AGPUWrangler  7.1.18
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    7.1.18
|IOGraphics!F   597
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  336.60.1
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!ASyntheticGame!C  10.7.1
>!AXsanScheme   3
>!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.81
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!ABCMWLANCoreMac   1.0.0
|IO80211!F  1200.13.0
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
>!AOLYHALMac    1
|IOSerial!F 11
>corecapture    1.0.4
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1150.2
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  554
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  235.140.2
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  482.120.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  482.120.2
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ACyrus    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   5.0.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
>watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0
```

Comment: Have you tested a clean OS, or Safe Boot mode? How much memory did you put in? Are they both new sticks? Have you tried with one, then the other? (Both slots!)

Comment: Page fault errors are almost always RAM problems.

Comment: If it's new, return it to Apple and make them diagnose it, that's what a warranty is for.

Comment: @benwiggy I added 64GB - 32GB in each slot. I did a whole new OS and swapped them w/ each other. I bought the memory on Amazon - the OWC brand.

Comment: @IconDaemon do you think it's possible the new memory I bought is not good? Is there way to know or test memory to see if it is corrupted somehow?

Comment: RAM _might_ be bad. You could also have zapped the RAM yourself by not following strict static mitigation protocol. You don't indicate which Mac model - perhaps you got the wrong RAM? It is possible you purchased (or were sent) the incorrect RAM type. It is hard to diagnose from afar. Personally, I've always purchased RAM upgrades from [Data Memory Systems](https://www.datamemorysystems.com) and have only encountered one bad RAM carrier out of countless terabytes of RAM. _No financial or other ties to Data Memory Systems_ - just a satisfied customer of many years.